# The server starts accumulating queries, Thread has long waited in the semaphore

Tags: mysql, mariadb, semaphore

In the log file has a lot of rows (250 threads), type

```
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: --Thread 139956102706944 has waited at row0ins.cc line 1982 for 115.00 seconds the semaphore:
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55865ee04de0 created in file dict0dict.cc line 920
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: a writer (thread id 139953379993344) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: number of readers 4, waiters flag 1, lock_word: fffffffc
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: Last time write locked in file srv0srv.cc line 2029
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: --Thread 140022041876224 has waited at row0upd.cc line 181 for 275.00 seconds the semaphore:
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55865ee04de0 created in file dict0dict.cc line 920
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: a writer (thread id 139953379993344) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: number of readers 4, waiters flag 1, lock_word: fffffffc
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: Last time write locked in file srv0srv.cc line 2029
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: --Thread 139956075943680 has waited at row0ins.cc line 1982 for 524.00 seconds the semaphore:
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55865ee04de0 created in file dict0dict.cc line 920
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: a writer (thread id 139953379993344) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: number of readers 4, waiters flag 1, lock_word: fffffffc
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: Last time write locked in file srv0srv.cc line 2029
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: --Thread 139956085135104 has waited at row0undo.cc line 295 for 47.00 seconds the semaphore:
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55865ee04de0 created in file dict0dict.cc line 920
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: a writer (thread id 139953379993344) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: number of readers 4, waiters flag 1, lock_word: fffffffc
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: Last time write locked in file srv0srv.cc line 2029
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: --Thread 139953379993344 has waited at srv0srv.cc line 2029 for 556.00 seconds the semaphore:
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: X-lock (wait_ex) on RW-latch at 0x55865ee04de0 created in file dict0dict.cc line 920
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: a writer (thread id 139953379993344) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: number of readers 4, waiters flag 1, lock_word: fffffffc
Feb 28 16:11:57 - mysqld: Last time write locked in file srv0srv.cc line 2029
```

innodb_adaptive_hash_index is turn-off.

version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

We migrate a lot of data (6M rows = 160GB) between schemas, do it small parts (500rows) with pause between iterations
what can be changed so that the server does not have locks in the semaphore?

Comment: Have you been able to find a reason/solution?

Comment: I have the same problem, and searching for a solution. On my server there are not many transactions when the lock happen. Also innodb_adaptive_hash_index is turn-off.